# How to say "living a purposeful life" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

In Google it translates to "propositum animam viventem", but the translation itself goes different when it's translated back to English. I wonder what is the accurate translation for this phrase.

Thank you.

Comment: As a rule: never use Google translate, and especially for Latin, it's even worse than with other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given more context, my word choices might be better.

'Vivere vitam dignam' means living a worthy life. Alternatives include:

'Vivere vitam digniorem/dignissimam' means living a rather worthy/a very worthy life.

'Vivere vitam dignosam' means living a life abounding in worth.

I chose dignus-a-um because of it's exceedingly positive connotation, and because it's English cognate "dignified" felt appropriate. This translation has not been run through any databases, so I don't know if this usage is directly attested.

Comment: Why do you use the present participle? _vivens_ means "that lives". In order to use the verb as a subject, you need the infinitive _vivere_.

Comment: You're absolutely right! That's a mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

> Industriosam vitam vivere.

I would suggest this translation, since *industriosus* well represents the purpose and the action, deliberate and industrious. This adjective is from the late Latin, but derives form *industria*, meaning industry, purposefulness and diligence.

P.s. Distrust Google Translate :p